# Converting JSON string to hashmap and array using Jackson

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I have a json string that I'm trying to parse to java objects.My problem is that it contains a hashmap (or so I understand) of furniture objects and an array of vendors. I have no problem parsing the array of vendors, but cannot figure out the solution to parse the hashmap properly.

My JSON looks like:

```
 {
"furniture": [{
        "table": {
            "price": "200",
            "available": false,
            "dimensions": {
                "height": 5,
                "weight": 20
            }
        }
    },

    {
        "chair": {
            "price": 400,
            "dimensions": {
                "height": 3
            }
        }
    }
],
"vendors": [{
        "id": 3400,
        "name": "Andrew Wlkinson",
        "email": "andrewwilkinson@hmail.com"
    },

    {
        "id": 2344,
        "name": "Daniel Mitchell",
        "email": "danielmitch@hmail.com"
    }
]

}
```

And in my main function I am creating a mapper and trying to parse the whole thing at once and I guess that's where things go wrong.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data = objectMapper.readValue(new File("example.json"), Data.class);
```

Data class contains both furniture as a hashmap and vendors as an array.
 So if someone could point me in the right direction or better way to do it, that will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Data {
private Vendor[] vendors;
Map<String, Attributes> furniture = new HashMap<String, Attributes>(); 

   public Vendor[] getVendors() {
        return vendors;
    }

 public void setVendors(Vendor[] vendors) {
        this.vendors = vendors;
    }
 public Map<String, Attributes>  getFurniture() {
        return furniture;
    }

 public void setFurniture(Map<String, Attributes> furniture) {
        thisfurniture = furniture;
    }
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
 `Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: sample.json; line: 2, column: 2] (through reference chain: Data["furniture"])`
```

Comment: Please post the Data class as well as the result you're getting at compile time or runtime.

Comment: The JSON you have provided is not valid, please provide valid JSON.

Comment: @jordanpg added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

In the json you have mentioned, furniture represents an array. You need to change it something like this:

```
{ "furniture" :
 { "table": { 
     "price": 200,
     "available": false,
      "dimensions": {"height":23, "weight":20"}}},
   "chair": {
      "price": 400,
      "dimensions": {"height":3}},

  "vendors":
  [{ "id": 3400,
     "name": "Andrew Wlkinson",
     "email": "andrewwilkinson@hmail.com",
   },

   { "id": 2344,
     "name": "Daniel Mitchell",
     "email": "danielmitch@hmail.com",
   }]}
```

Comment: it's a school task, I can't change json unfortunately

Comment: It's not optional.  Jackson will not deserialize invalid JSON.  Put it into an IDE and try to format it.  It has multiple problems.